# What does setTimeoutTimestamp() do in mapGroupsWithState?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Can someone help with the working of `setTimeoutTimestamp()` in `mapGroupsWithState()`?

Does `setTimeoutTimestamp()` delete the state after it crosses the duration specified?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Scala Docs on [GroupState](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/GroupState.html) the method `setTimeoutTimestamp` returns a `Unit`. It only *sets* the timeout.

Therefore, nothing is happening unless you explicitly check if the state has timed out and then remove it. An example is also given in the linked documentation and briefly shown below:

```scala
if (state.hasTimedOut) {  // If called when timing out, remove the state
    state.remove()
} else {
    ...
}
```